# How do I create XML using Nokogiri::XML::Builder with a hyphen in the element name?

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to build an XML document using Nokogiri. Some of the elements have hyphens in them. Here's an example:

```
require "nokogiri"
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.foo_bar "hello"
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Which produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo_bar>hello</foo_bar>
```

However, when I try:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.foo-bar "hello"
end
```

I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
  xml.foo-bar "hello"
```

Now I realise this is because the hyphen is being interpreted as `foo MINUS bar`.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here you go:

```
require 'nokogiri'

b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send(:"fooo-bar", "hello")
end

puts b.to_xml
```

Comment: where does the hello come in?  xml.send(:"foo-bar", "hello")?

Comment: Where is it documented in official Nokogiri documentation? can you please share a link?

Comment: @yegor256 here you go: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder

Comment: Bit late to the party here, but that :"xx-aaa" syntax is the standard Ruby way of making a symbol when the syntax won't work for you

Answer (score 30):

Bart Vandendriessche's answer works but there is a simpler solution if you only want a text field within the element.

```
require 'nokogiri'

b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send(:"foo-bar", 'hello')
end

puts b.to_xml
```

Generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo-bar>hello</foo-bar>
```

If you need them to be nested then you can pass a block

```
require 'nokogiri'

b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send(:'foo-bar') {
    xml.send(:'bar-foo', 'hello')
  }
end

puts b.to_xml
```

Generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo-bar>
  <bar-foo>hello</bar-foo>
</foo-bar>
```

Answer (score 4):

Aaron Patterson's answer is correct and will work for element names containing any character that may otherwise be interpreted by the Ruby parser.

Answering Angela's question: to place text inside a element created this way you can do something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send(:'foo.bar') {
    xml.text 'hello'
  }
end

puts b.to_xml
```