# Nokogiri::XML::Builder#send does nothing

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

In Nokogiri 1.6.1, I'm observing the following behavior:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml1 = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.p
end
xml1.to_xml #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>\n<p/>

xml2 = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send(:p)
end
xml2.to_xml #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

So, `.p` produces a `<p/>` element, while `.send(:p)` produces nothing. What's going on here? This behavior seems to contradict everything I've read about Nokogiri's API. It also seems illogical in terms of Ruby's semantics, unless that class overrides `#send`.

The same also happens with `.send("p")`.

For reference:

[How do I create XML using Nokogiri::XML::Builder with a hyphen in the element name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947307/how-do-i-create-xml-using-nokogirixmlbuilder-with-a-hyphen-in-the-element-na)

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4406393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby’s [`send` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) will invoke private methods as well as public ones. In this case it ends up calling the [`Kernel#p` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p), which is a private method on all objects. You can see this by passing another argument to `p` that will be printed:

```
xml.send(:p, "A message that will be printed")
```

Another way to demonstrate this would be to use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send), which doesn’t look at private methods and so will trigger `method_missing` and generate the tag.

```
xml.public_send(:p)
```

Of course you don’t really need to use `public_send`, since `p` doesn’t use any special characters and you can use it directly as a method:

```
xml.p
```